# Where am I going wrong with Elasticsearch _delete_by_query?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm fairly new to Elasticsearch and trying to periodically delete documents using the *_delete_by_query* API (I fully appreciate I should probably be using time based indices to make this easier, and will be updating the indexing structure in due course, but for now I need to get this working).

My index contains fields called ServiceName, message and timestamp (among others) and my requirement is pretty simple. I want to delete documents where ServiceName equals a specific value (myService), the message does NOT equal either of two specific values (Starting* and Finished* as I want to retain the first and last log message from any trace history), and the document is old than one day. I am using the *_delete_by_query* endpoint with the following payload:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "filter": [{
                    "match_all": {}
                },
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "ServiceName": {
                            "query": "myService"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                         "@timestamp": {
                        "lte": "now-1d"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [],
            "must_not": [{
                "bool": {
                    "should": [{
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "message": "Starting*"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match_phrase": {
                                "message": "Finished*"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "minimum_should_match": 1
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the query using the *_search* API, it returns the data I'd expect to be deleted, but when I issued the same query to *_delete_by_query*, it deleted documents that were not returned in the **search** results. I am using AWS Elasticsearch Service. Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong or should this work? I thought initially it might be the `minimum_should_match` property however the documentation seems to suggest this is irrelevant in this case

Comment: `...it deleted documents that were returned in the search results` which is what you'd expect right?

Comment: Ha - typo there. It deleted documents that did not get returned by the search results, is what I should have said. Will edit

Comment: Ok, it's more logical that way ;-) I find it very surprising though... How many results do you get for the search query? and how many were actually deleted with the same query?

Comment: Hmm maybe I genuinely did something wrong. I'll give it another go as I was surprised too. We are talking about 20 million documents as it's built up over time

Comment: Thanks everyone for comments - I've reworked indexing strategy to use date based indices so purging old data is now a simple case of deleting the index

Comment: Great, yes, that's how you're supposed to be handling time-based data. Much easier

Answer (score 0):

This is strange. Can you check if the the number of hits are same or not? Search results in kibana are truncated so that could be a reason of not seeing a particular documents in search results but in deleted documents.

If that is not the case, it will great if you could share sample of two documents.

- Doc A: Gets listed in search and also gets deleted.
- Doc B: Not listed in search but gets deleted.

This will help in replicating the issue at my end and get back to you.